# How do I store my selected favorites in localstorage? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have code for displaying birds, images of the birds and tags. There is an option to favorite certain birds with a favorite button. I want to store the birds that are selected as a favorite in localstorage, how do I do this? When I try to store the favBtn.value it won't display anything. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also shared my html code now

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);

const cardsContainer = document.querySelector('#cards');
const aside = document.querySelector('#wrapper aside');



/*
 array with birds
*/
const birds={
    'Koolmees':{
        src:'https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?koolmees',
        tags:'rotterdam, koolmees, kleine vogel'
    },
    'Specht':{
        src:'https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?specht',
        tags:'specht, nijmegen, kleine vogel'
    },
    'kerkuil':{
        src:'https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?snowowl',
        tags:'uil, eindhoven, grote vogel, roofvogel'
    }
};


/*
  if there is no `figcaption` below the image it will add the caption and
  assign the `tags` text which is assigned to the image as a dataset attribute
*/
const clickhandler=function(e){
    let fig=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('figcaption');
    if( fig==null ){
        fig=document.createElement('figcaption');
        fig.textContent=this.dataset.tags
        e.target.parentNode.appendChild( fig );
    }else{
        e.target.parentNode.removeChild(fig)
    }
    aside.textContent=fig==null ? '' : this.dataset.tags;
}


/*
 this function changes te color in the button
*/
function setColor(el, color) {
    if (el.value == 0) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        el.value = 1;
    } else {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
        el.value = 0;
    }
}


function init(){

    document.getElementById('cards').querySelectorAll('.card').forEach( card => {
        card.addEventListener('click',clickhandler );
    });
}


/*
 adding elements to cards
*/
function addCard(birdImage, birdName, birdTags){// now takes 3 arguments
    let item = document.createElement('flex-item');
    item.classList.add('card');
    item.dataset.tags=birdTags; //assign the tags as a dataset atttribute
    cardsContainer.appendChild(item)
    let favBtn = document.createElement('button')
    favBtn.innerText = '❤'
    favBtn.value = 0
    favBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'setColor(this, "#101010")')
    favBtn.classList.add('fav-btn')
    item.appendChild(favBtn)
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = birdImage;
    img.title=birdTags; //  tags also assigned for the img title
    item.appendChild(img)

    let name = document.createElement('div')
    name.innerText = birdName
    item.appendChild(name)
}

/*
  Using the `object.keys` method allows us to quickly
  iterate through each sub-object. The `key` is the bird name.
*/
function addCards(){
    Object.keys( birds ).forEach( key => {
        let bird=birds[ key ];
        addCard( bird.src, key, bird.tags )
    })
}

addCards()
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="magazine zonder fetch">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="Micha van der Willigen">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Bird magazine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <header><p1>Vogel magazine voor vogelspotters!</p1></header>
    <main>
        <p>
            <!-- with these buttons you can set the website in full screen -->
            <button class="start" id="startFull">Start fullscreen on the whole page</button>
            <button id="exit">Exit fullscreen</button>
        </p>
        <!-- here the cards with the birds will be displayed -->
        <flex-container id="cards">

        </flex-container>
    </main>
    <aside>Click on a bird to display the tags!</aside>
    <footer><p>Website door Micha van der Willigen</p></footer>
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullscreen.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your HTML also ?

Comment: @ArchanaAgivale I have included the HTML in my question now

Comment: You say, you _try_ to save `favBtn.value` but I can't find such a line except for `favBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'setColor(this, "#101010")')` which I would recommend to replace with an `addEventListener()` call.

Comment: Can I use the addEventListener call to see which button was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a couple of functions to load and to write to local storage

```
const loadBird = () => {
    if (localStorage['favouriteBird']) 
        // If a saved bird exists
        savedBird = JSON.parse(localStorage['favouriteBird'])
    else 
        // No saved birds
        savedBird = {}
}

const saveBird = () => {
    localStorage['favouriteBird'] = JSON.stringify(favouriteBird)
}
```

To use in your code, just add `loadBird()` into the init function and also add a `favouriteBird` variable at the top of your script. 
 
 Whenever a favourite bird is updated, just call the `saveBird()` function 
 
Just change the variable names to whatever you want, and also add an `if` statement to check if `savedBird` is `null` or `undefined` and if it is just define it as the starting bird.

Comment: I would recommend to use `localStorage.getItem()` and `localStorage.setItem()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried to use your functions but I still dont know how I assign the favorited birds to the favouriteBird variable. I can get the button to change color when clicked, but i also need to know which button was clicked for example

Comment: My last project actually had a very similar problem. Maybe you could try having a variable somewhere in your script which refers to a chosen bird. Maybe add an event listener for each button which would change the variable to whatever bird the button corresponds with? And after the button is clicked it just calls the `saveBird` function.